# Double comparison failing in Java

Tags: java, object, double, comparison

Why does the first `if-statement` return true and the second false?

Isn't `100000000000000.032` in the first `if-statement` also turned into a new Double that is different to dd?

```java
Double dd = 100000000000000.032;
if(dd == 100000000000000.032) {
    System.out.println("gaga");
}

Double ee = 100000000000000.032;
if(dd == ee) {
    System.out.println("gaga");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you follow [Majed Badawi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7486313/majed-badawi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154372/1554195) to use `equals()` because you compare object instances, or you modify your code like below:

```
double dd = 100000000000000.032
if( dd == 100000000000000.032 ) 
{
    System.out.println( "gaga" );
}

double ee = 100000000000000.032;
if( dd == ee ) 
{
    System.out.println( "gaga" );
}
```

Note that `dd` and `ee` are now of the primitive type `double` (with a lowercase 'D').

In your sample, the first comparison worked because internally, it was interpreted as:

```
… 
if( dd.doubleValue() == 100000000000000.032 ) 
…
```

This behaviour is called 'Autoboxing/-unboxing' and was introduced with Java 5; for versions before Java 5, your code would not compile at all.

Comment: Ah, that is the answer. I was expecting 100000000000000.032 to be auto-boxed into a new Double-object. But instead dd is unboxed and we get a comparison of primitives. Now it all makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

Since you are comparing two objects in the second `if-statement`, you should be using the `equals` method as follows:

```
if(dd.equals(ee))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first if:
- you use == to test an object with a primitive; the object is converted to primitive and the two are equal.
In the second if:
- you compare two different objects.

Try ee == ee and see that it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Double is object so == won't give required result, use .equals method

Answer (score 0):

`==` tests if the objects are the same object, not that they have the same value.  In your example `dd` and `ee` are distinct objects even though they have the same value.  So if you want to compare their values you will need to use the [equals method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Here is a small test to help you get a handle on it:

```java
package stackoverflow;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class QuickTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Double number1 = 100000000000000.032;
        Double number2 = 100000000000000.032;

        System.out.println("Do they point to the same object? " + (number1 == number2));

        System.out.println("Are they equal, do they have the same value? " + (number1.equals(number2)));

        Double number3 = 100000000000000.032;
        Double number4 = number3;

        System.out.println("Do they point to the same object? " + (number3 == number4));

        System.out.println("Are they equal, do they have the same value? " + (number3.equals(number4)));
    }
}
```

This prints out the following:

```
Do they point to the same object? false
Are they equal, do they have the same value? true
Do they point to the same object? true
Are they equal, do they have the same value? true
```